# What are the causes of an AS not being able to work under SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am running into a rather aggravating issue with the "AS" keyword in SQL server.  I am doing multiple LEFT JOINs and using the AS keyword to create aliases for the result sets.   I've tried to define an alias on a particular query and getting an error stating "Incorrect syntax near AS".  The query will go through successfully, but SQL server is just not allowing me to define an alias.

I've researched and attempted to find some more thorough documentation on what can and cannot be done with the AS keyword.  I'm also seriously considering the possibility that I've written a built-in somewhere and am just missing it.

I've extracted parts of other SQL I've written involving multiple JOINs, but I'm running into the same issue.  Here is an example of the query I'm dealing with now:

```
SELECT
    D.ProjectID [Project ID],
    D.VendorID [Vendor ID],
    VND.VendorName [Name],
    D.Modifiedby [User Modified]
FROM
    ( SELECT
        ProjectID,
        VendorID,
        Modifiedby
    FROM [Project].[ProjectDocument]
    ) AS D

LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT
        VendorID,
        VendorName
    FROM [VendorTable].[Vendor]
    ) AS VND
ON D.VendorID = VND.VendorID AS V
```

Are there any reasons as to why the AS keyword would be rejected by SQL server?

Comment: Removing the trailing `AS V` takes care of the problem. You would need to wrap the entire query in parentheses if you want to alias the whole thing.

Comment: Why are you adding the `as V` at the end? Why are you aggravated? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for SUPER late reply on this.  Ended up figuring this out.   This was part of a larger query using many aliases.  When I broke it down, I couldn't pin down why some of my aliases seemed to be working and some did not (this particular one).   I'm not exactly sure how SO works as far as unanswered questions, but it was probably my bad for not really explaining it clearly.   What's my next move?

Answer (score 0):

The last statement says:

```
ON D.VendorID = VND.VendorID AS V
```

Remove the `AS V` from the back.